# Check checkbox in a list dynamically

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am working on a checkbox listview. What I have done so far is populated the list from local db, get all the checked item's databse id using the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and store it in a separate table in my local db. This is how my code looks:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(con);
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            switch (getItemViewType(position)){
                case DYNAMIC_OBJECTIVE:
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.objective_list_view, null);
                    break;
                case STATIC_OBJECTIVE:
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_objective_list_view, null);
                    break;
            }

            switch (getItemViewType(position)){
                case DYNAMIC_OBJECTIVE:
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.objectiveCheckBox);
                    checkBox.setText(((Objectives)list.get(position)).getObjectiveTitle());

                    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                selectedObjectivesMap.put(((Objectives)list.get(position)).getObjectiveID(), "YES");
                            }else{
                                selectedObjectivesMap.put(((Objectives)list.get(position)).getObjectiveID(), "NO");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case STATIC_OBJECTIVE:
                    TextView checkBoxOther = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.objectiveOtherCheckBox);
                    final TextView objectiveOtherET = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.objectiveOtherEditText);
                    checkBoxOther.setText((String)list.get(position));
                    //ll = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutOther);
                    //viewNew = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_objective_row, null);
                    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addOtherObjectiveTextBox);
                    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked123", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.otherobjectivedialog);

                            final EditText enterObjET = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.enterObjEditText);
                            Button closeEnterObjBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeEnterObjDialog);
                            Button objConfirmBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.enterObjConfirmBtn);

                            closeEnterObjBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                            objConfirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    String enteredObj = enterObjET.getText().toString();
                                    if(enteredObj.equals("")){
                                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please write a objective", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }else {
                                        objectiveOtherET.setText(objectiveOtherET.getText().toString()+ " \n" + enteredObj);
                                        otherObjList.add(enteredObj);
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            dialog.show();

/*                            LinearLayout linearLayoutNew = new LinearLayout(con);
                            linearLayoutNew.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                            et = new EditText(con);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            et.setLayoutParams(p);
                            et.setHint("Set some objective");
                            linearLayoutNew.addView(et);
                            ll.addView(linearLayoutNew);*/
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }

        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

and this is how I'm populating my list:

```
ArrayList<Object> objectiveList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor crs = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ItemsTable.TABLE_OBJECTIVE +"", null);

        while(crs.moveToNext())
        {
            String title = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("title"));
            int objectiveID = crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex("id"));
            objectiveList.add(new Objectives(objectiveID, title));
        }
        crs.close();
        objectiveList.add("Others");

        listView.setAdapter(new ObjectivesAdapter(getActivity(), objectiveList));
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

**PROBLEM:**
This all works perfect but now I want to edit the same information. All I want is the existing checkbox id's (that were checked and store in my db) should be checked when I come back to this view. I have queried the data and I have the IDs but I don't know how to check the checkboxes based on their IDs.

```
            Cursor crsCheckObj = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ItemsTable.TABLE_PLAN_OBJECTIVE_MAP +" WHERE "
                    + ItemsTable.COLUMN_PLAN_OBJECTIVE_MAP_PLANID +"='"+ Info.getInstance().getPlanVisitID() +"'", null);
            if(crsCheckObj.getCount() > 0){
                while (crsCheckObj.moveToNext()){
                    //Here IDs should match in order to check the checkboxes
                }

            }
            crsCheckObj.close();
```

Comment: Checkbox.setChecked(boolean checked);  ?  Word of caution though, when calling setChecked Checkbox will call through to checkedchangedlistener so probably better to setclicklistener and manually call Checkbox.unChecked()

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but I have to let the loop know which checkbox to set true and that is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Check the id in getView...

Comment: I didn't understand your point @MidasLefko. I have the IDs in the getview method I just want to compare them with the checkbox IDs. An example of what you're trying to say would be perfect for me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `setTag()` for your checkbox like this:

```
checkBox.setTag(((Objectives)list.get(position)).getObjectiveID());
```

then all you need to is something like this:

```
Cursor crsCheckObj = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ ItemsTable.TABLE_PLAN_OBJECTIVE_MAP +" WHERE "
                            + ItemsTable.COLUMN_PLAN_OBJECTIVE_MAP_PLANID +"='"+ Info.getInstance().getPlanVisitID() +"'", null);
                    if(crsCheckObj.getCount() > 0){
                        while (crsCheckObj.moveToNext()){
                            if(((Integer) checkBox.getTag()) == crsCheckObj.getInt(crsCheckObj.getColumnIndex("objective_id"))){
                                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    crsCheckObj.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you can simply use `checkbox.setChecked(true)`

if it do not work then try following:

```
checkbox.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }
        },100);
```